# Looking for an example docker-compose file to have traefik to reverse proxy both a container and non container service

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

I want to be able to use traefik so that I can reverse proxy both container and non-container services.  And I’d like to be able to use a docker-compose file so it is easily setup and torn down.  I thought this would be a common request, but I can’t find a unified example.  And since I’m still really new to docker, this is a little outside of my wheelhouse.  Ideally the docker-compose file would:

- install the traefik container, including authentication so that traefik can be managed with a WebUI
- Have traefik use Let’s encrypt to generate and maintain SSL certificates that traefik will use to reverse proxy both docker and non-docker services
- install a sample container (like Apache) that will be tagged so traefik will reverse proxy to  https://apache.example.com (http automatically redirects)
- reverse-proxy a non-container service at http://192.168.1.15:8085 to https://foobar.example.com (http automatically redirects)

I’ve seen plenty of examples on how to use traefik and to tag new containers so that they are reversed proxied, but precious few on how to reverse proxy non-docker services.  I’m sure I’m not the only one who would appreciate an example that does both at the same time.